# How to create a matrix with as.matrix function?

Tags: matrix

I'm trying to convert a vector into a matrix using `as.matrix`, but I can't determine the number of rows and cols:

```
D=seq(1,100, by=4)
E= as.matrix(D, ncol=3, nrow=4)
```

What I get for E is:

```
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    5
 [3,]    9
 [4,]   13
 [5,]   17
 [6,]   21
 [7,]   25
 [8,]   29
 [9,]   33
[10,]   37
[11,]   41
[12,]   45
[13,]   49
[14,]   53
[15,]   57
[16,]   61
[17,]   65
[18,]   69
[19,]   73
[20,]   77
[21,]   81
[22,]   85
[23,]   89
[24,]   93
[25,]   97
```

How can I fix this?